# Convert list to dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Is there any way I can convert this type of output into a Dataframe? Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['Orange', 'Apple']]
[['C', 'D'], ['Coconut', 'Lemon']]
[['E'], ['Mango', 'Strawberry']]
```

```
I want to turn the output into a dataframe like this:

`     x1         X2
0   A,B   Orange, Apple
1   C,D   Coconut, Lemon
2   E     Mango, Strawberry`
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your starting data is in a list, and you would like to join each list with a comma, this should work:

```
l = [[['A', 'B'], ['Orange', 'Apple']],
    [['C', 'D'], ['Coconut', 'Lemon']],
    [['E'], ['Mango', 'Strawberry']]]

df = pd.DataFrame([[', '.join(v) for v in i] for i in l],columns = ['x1','x2'])
```

Also `stack()` with `str.join()` is an option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['x1','x2']).stack().str.join(', ').unstack()
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l).applymap(', '.join).rename(lambda x: 'x{}'.format(x+1),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     x1                 x2
0  A, B      Orange, Apple
1  C, D     Coconut, Lemon
2     E  Mango, Strawberry
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this data to a list

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[['A', 'B'], ['Orange', 'Apple']],
        [['C', 'D'], ['Coconut', 'Lemon']],
        [['E'], ['Mango', 'Strawberry']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x1', 'x2'])
```

so df looks like

```bash
       x1                   x2
0  [A, B]      [Orange, Apple]
1  [C, D]     [Coconut, Lemon]
2     [E]  [Mango, Strawberry]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {"x1":[["A", "B"], ["C", "D"], ["E"]],
    "x2":[["Orange", "Apple"], ["Coconut", "Lemon"], ["Mango", "Strawberry"]]}
)
```